# How to open a file from a directory inside the python directory

Tags: python

I have a folder called data inside my python folder which is full of text files, each named a state's abbreviation ("NY", "CA", "RI", etc.).  I need to take user input of the name of a state and then open that file.

I tried this:

```
file = ""
file = open("NY", "r").read().splitelines()
```

but it came up with nothing in the directory.  How can I open individual files from the folder?

Comment: Possibly you're looking for `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'NY')`, which will open files relative to the directory containing the .py file rather than the current working directory.

Comment: @o11c, took the liberty to wrtie up an answer using this idea.. Gave you a thumbs up ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
from os.path import join, dirname

data_dir = join(dirname(__file__), 'data')

with open(join(data_dir, raw_input('Enter state: '))) as f:
    print(f.readlines())
```

This code makes a base dir variable and joins it with the state name. When executed you will see

```
brunsgaard@archbook ~/t/test> python test.py
Enter state: NY
['Hello, I am the NY file\n']
```

This example was run in the context of the following diretory structure.

```
.
├── data
│   └── NY
└── test.py
```